# What does "Critical error detected c0000374" mean, and how to solve it?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw-w64

I encountered this crash upon cleanup stage of a program, and I couldn't find the problem. From what I've researched, the problem usually happens when you have a memory corruption, but in my case I can't understand where it should come from. The only real object is the std::stringstream, but that should be managed automatically. The custom object is little more than a wrapper. I'm not doing anything exciting with heap allocation here. When running the program in gdb, it says:

> Destruct Foo

^ That's just my own print. Next the actual error starts:

> warning: Critical error detected c0000374

traceback:

```
#0  0x00007fffa662f3a3 in ntdll!RtlIsZeroMemory () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007fffa6638162 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007fffa663844a in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x00007fffa663e0d1 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#4  0x00007fffa6555bf0 in ntdll!RtlGetCurrentServiceSessionId () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x00007fffa65547b1 in ntdll!RtlFreeHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x00007fffa6279c9c in msvcrt!free () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x00007fff72772ef0 in std::locale::_Impl::~_Impl() () from D:\mypath\lib\libfoo.dll
#8  0x00007fff72771ce3 in std::locale::_Impl::_M_remove_reference() ()
   from D:\mypath\lib\libfoo.dll
#9  0x00007fff7271131b in bar::Foo::~Foo (this=0xa111dffa40, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
```

script.cpp:

```
#include <foo.hpp>

int test_foo(){
  bar::Foo foo;
  return 0;
}
```

foo.hpp:

```
namespace bar{

class Foo{
public:
  std::stringstream ss;
  ~Foo();
};

}// namespace bar
```

foo.cpp:

```
namespace bar{

Foo::~Foo(){
  printf("Destruct Foo\n");
}

}// namespace bar
```

My original program was much more complex, but I stripped it down to the smallest reproducer. If I put all in the same file, it doesn't crash, so this leads me to believe there's some problem with the dll.

P.S. I'm using Windows 10 with mingw, gcc 12.2.0, Cmake 3.21.0

Comment: The (implicitly defined) `Foo` constructor is inline, but the destructor isn't. So `std::stringstream` instance is constructed in the EXE, but destroyed in the DLL. It appears that the two are built in such a way that they don't share a common heap manager.

Comment: 0xC0000374 : A heap has been corrupted.

Comment: I'd solve it by not using a DLL.

Comment: @Eljay I agree.  I never do.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank you very much! To get this to work I only needed to add an empty constructor to class Foo. Very unintuitive as you'd think an empty function doesn't do anything!